# Jquery lista desplegable con PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy haciendo una lista desplegable siguiendo esta referencia
https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_collapsible

Funciona la lista desplegable pero me aparece un error en la consola de google 
y cuando intento guardar estilos en css me aparece un extraño error. El problema se encuentra en como nombro jquery, cuando lo elimino se restablece.

```
<?php 

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
echo "<html>\n";
echo "<head>\n";
echo "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n";
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css\">\n";
echo "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js\"></script>\n";
echo "<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js\"></script>\n";
echo "</head>";

//code
```

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token'<'**  para referir a la primera linea '<!DOCTYPE html>' , si lo elimino a la segunda.. y en el panel de estilo personalizado al guardar **Parece que algo salió mal. Espera un par de segundos y vuelve a intentarlo**. Todo eso desaparece al eliminar estas lineas.

Comment: Pero, ¿hay más cosas antes de tu etiqueta de apertura de bloque PHP? Puedes intentar a ponerlo así: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head> <body>`  y luego abres el bloque de código PHP: `<?php `  y asegúrate de cerrar al final con `</body> </html>`

Comment: Le agregue .. pero mismo error.. mejora agregandole echo " y conservandolo en php. Esto aparece en consola https://pasteboard.co/IPENkmw.jpg y asi empieza mi codigo https://pasteboard.co/IPEMuBd.jpg ( es un plugin tiene 2000 lineas). Al final del php cerre ambas etiquetas.

Comment: La forma habitual de hacerlo es como te indiqué, poniendo el `DOCTYPE` y los encabezados antes de la apertura de bloque PHP, aunque no debería de dar problemas de ninguno de los dos modos. Creo que el error se debe a la línea en blanco al principio, deberías quitarla y el error debería desaparecer al menos en ese archivo, porque en la parte superior se ve que hay `18` errores en otras partes.

Comment: Corresponden a google places los errores 17. Lo que me llama la atención es que se aplica la libreria a todo wordpress, incluso el admin, es esto correcto?

Comment: ¿Qué librería? Si no la quieres ver en el Admin hay formas en Wordpress de añadir las librerías sólo en ciertas partes o de agregarlas para uso de plugins.

Comment: Ahi pude resolverlo. Descargue las librerías y las añadi dentro de una función. esto hace que no se aplique al admin ni tenga conflictos. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si estás trabajando en Wordpress tienes que revisar la documentación sobre crear tus propios plugins, allí explican la forma de agregar librerías en modo no conflict y dan otras directivas que conviene aplicar para evitar este tipo de problemas y futuros errores en tu desarrollo.

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no encierras todas las etiquetes en comillas simples para evitarte la fatiga y disminuir el error de escape de tu código php?